# Match a string but not if it contains another string

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a regex to match `[ERROR]` but not `[ERROR].*Internal Error`. I am not very good at regexes. But I tried this and it didn't work :-

```
\[ERROR\].*(?!.*[Ii]nternal [Ee]rror).
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Against `[ERROR] Internal Error`, your pattern matches as follows:

```
    +------------------------ pos  0, len  7  "[ERROR]"
    |    +------------------- pos  7, len 15  " Internal Error"
    |    |             +----- pos 22, len  0  ""
    |    |             |
 ___|___ |  ___________|____________
/       \/\/                        \
\[ERROR\].*(?!.*[Ii]nternal [Ee]rror)
```

You need to make sure that `Internal Error` doesn't start at any of the positions after `[ERROR]`.

```
/\[ERROR\](?:(?![Ii]nternal [Ee]rror).)*\z/s
```

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`

---

That said, the `\z` allows you to simplify the above to the following:

```
/\[ERROR\](?!.*[Ii]nternal [Ee]rror)/s
```

Answer (score 2):

use two regexp for clarity / simplicity  (!~ means "does not match")

```
if ( ($a =~ /\[ERROR\]/) && ($a !~ /[Ii]nternal [Ee]rror/)) {
    #do your stuff
}
```

Comment: True for `Internal Error [ERROR]`, but that's probably ok despite what the OP said.

Answer (score -1):

`(\[ERROR\])(?:.(?![Ii]nternal [Ee]rror))+.`

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: Fails (1) for `[ERROR]Internal Error.`.

Comment: Fails (0) for `[ERROR]f`